# HTTPS for /wp-admin/ and HTTP for everything else?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http, https, wordpress

I'm running a WordPress site on a shared Apache server on Dreamhost. I already have `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);` set (and working) in my wp-config.php so that SSL is used for the /wp-admin/ directory.

Can you point me to a .htaccess set of rules that will still maintain /wp-admin/ over https, but redirect any other directory/URL to use http? All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use https for everything? As long as you're setting it up, you might as well take full advantage. Unless, I suppose, you're using a self-signed cert, in which case it wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: I use a cdn, and that is currently only set up for http. Plus, Google results are pointing to http and https. I would rather just have http.

Comment: @ErikA There is a huge performance risk to deal with when 'just' using HTTPS. Every page which is requested needs to go through the 3 way handshake and every page that is serviced also comes with the overhead of encryption.

Comment: @emtunc - yes, there is a bit of overhead, but surely not a *huge* performance hit. If your server is that close to pegging its CPU that it cannot handle serving via SSL, then you have other problems to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Note that if your admin interface loads images, CSS, JS, etc. out of a directory other than /wp-admin/ (which by default it does), this will probably make a warning appear on your browser (and will likely compromise the security you were trying to gain).  You can add something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|jpg|gif|png)$
```

to resolve that, just keep adding extensions until you've got everything covered.

Comment: I tried the above. When I visit the root domain via https it doesn't redirect to http. Any ideas?

Comment: In a .htaccess, drop the leading `/` from the RewriteRule.

Comment: Yes +1! +1 for your answer and the checkmark! Thank you!

Comment: A .js is coming over http, rather than https. I have: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|jpg|gif|png)$ right after the first line that has the /wp-admin/. Is that correct?

Comment: At first glance at least, that looks like it should work.  Is it?  Note that it won't rewrite broken HTML; if the HTML tells the browser to fetch the JS via HTTP, that will still happen.  This is just to prevent errors from appearing when the HTML is correct.

Comment: Yes, it works now. I had to restart my browser. Many thanks!